# What does 'lose one's step' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

It sounds like some sort of an idiom, but I haven't found it in any dictionary. Maybe, it means 'lose one's pace', doesn't it? The context suggests it.

> Don’t **lose your step**
>
> Now we’re almost there
>
> Go wash your face and comb your hair

*(an excerpt from the song My Love for Evermore by the band Hillbilly Moon Explosion)*

Comment: Yeah - basically '*Don't falter now*'

Comment: It's not a particularly common idiomatic use with the sense of losing one's *momentum, willingness / ability (to continue)* - i.e. ***Don't give up***. Most written instances of ***Don't lose your step*** actually carry the sense more often expressed by *Don't lose your **footing*** (be careful not to ***slip / trip over***). But song lyrics often feature "unusual" phrasing, and it's not always important that everyone should understand the exact same meaning for any given expression (if they even bother thinking to that level of detail anyway).

Comment: I think it comes out of group dancing. To "keep one's step" would mean to keep putting your feet (your step) where the dance pattern indicates. So it means, keep up with what you are meant to be doing, in correct time and in the correct order.

Comment: @puppetsockreinstateMonica: I'd have thought that would normally be *to keep **in** step*. But I'm not from the land of the line-dancers (the US), so I wouldn't really know.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica  To "keep in step" would be more like to stay in formation in marching. That is, a group of soldiers march  "in *lock* step."

Comment: @puppetsockreinstateMonica: It's true that ***march** in step* is [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dance+in+step%2Cmarch+in+step&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdance%20in%20step%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmarch%20in%20step%3B%2Cc0) than ***dance** in step*....

Comment: ...but  But *lose your **step*** is [rare compared to](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lose+your+step%2Close+your+footing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Close%20your%20step%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Close%20your%20footing%3B%2Cc0) *lose your **footing***, which was the main point I was making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "lose one's step" generally means to break the rhythm of one's walking, usually unintentionally.  So, as an example, if you're walking along normally and suddenly hit a patch of slippery ground which causes you to have to stop and regain your stability (but not actually fall), you would have lost your step.

As @Smock commented, it is similar to "falter", although "falter" often has implications that your progress has been broken because you are hesitant or reluctant about something, and can also suggest that it is a more significant or enduring situation, whereas "losing one's step" does not really imply any hesitancy, just that *something* made you break your normal stride for a moment.

Usually, losing one's step is due to losing stable footing in some way, but not always (you could lose your step because something startled you, for example).  If you trip over something, or stumble in some way, that could also be described as losing your step (though in many cases, I suspect people would choose to use the more explicit "trip" or "stumble" instead).  It is generally not said when something actually makes one fall down, or if you have to stop walking because something is in your way, etc.  It also generally implies that the condition is something that can be quickly recovered from (though it doesn't necessarily mean that it *was* recovered from quickly, just that it normally could have been).

You are correct that "lose one's pace" is very similar.  I think the only real distinction between the two is that "losing one's step" implies a quickly recoverable condition (i.e. only one of your steps was out of place, but the next one could be normal again), whereas "losing one's pace" implies that your rhythm has been disrupted in a way that stays disrupted for at least some time (i.e. it's not easy to get your pace back to normal).

In the context of the quoted song lyrics, I think the phrase has pretty much the same meaning as usual, basically "don't stumble / falter / etc".

Answer (score 0):

In that precise case, the meaning would be similar to "lose oneself" (figuratively, of course) or, indeed, to "lose one's pace".

Comment: To the extent that ***pace*** is used with this general sense, it's more often attached to the definite article - *drop / increase / force / slacken / maintain / set / step up / slow **the pace*** (where ***lose*** isn't at all common). But the possessive is certainly much more natural with *Don't lose **your** step*.